# Convert file data into a string perl

Tags: perl

I have a file in which have comma separated  data below is the format of file :

```
560052400,
560052400,
560052400,
ABCF,
DEF,
FFRRR,
560052431,
```

Now what i am trying to do is to convert this data into a string a write into a file and in the new file format will be like :

```
560052400, 560052400, 560052400, ABCF, DEF, FFRRR, 560052431,
```

How we can do this in Perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "convert this data into a string", but to remove the newlines, all you need to do is `chomp` the input.

```
perl -pe 'chomp' input_file >output_file
```

If you like the spaces after the commas, a simple regex substitution will do.

```
perl -pe 's/\n/ /' input_file >output_file
```

To do either of these as part of a larger script, simply wrap it in a loop explicitly.

```
open(my $input, '<', 'input_filename');
open(my $output, '>', 'output_filename');
while (<$input>) {
  s/\n/ /; # Or whatever work you want to do to each line of the file
  print $output $_;
}
close $output;
close $input;
```

Comment: I was looking fro this only but I want to do this in a perl script not from a command prompt

Comment: Please test your answers before posting them. Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Always do error checking on I/O, e.g. `open(my $input, '<', 'input_filename') or die("open input_filename: $!\n")`